# Am I loading my js files correctly in the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

In main.js, I have:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){

  alert('foo');

});
```

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require main
```

In development. After running `rake assets:precompile`, I refresh any page, it executes `alert('foo')` twice. It's only supposed to do it once. It seems as if there are two copies of main.js being loaded.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you remove those precompiled assets and run in dev, does it only alert once?  Wondering if dev is loading both, compiled and the existing file.

Comment: Yeap, if I remove the precompiled assets. It alerts once. It seems like dev is loading both. Compiled and existing file? Is is supposed to do this?

Comment: Sounds like development mode is running both... I'm guessing there's a way to turn that off.  Regardless, it shouldn't happen in prod -- at least I'm guessing that :-)

Comment: Hmmm, I guess it won't happen in production since `config.serve_static_assets = false` exists in `config/environments/production.rb`. I put the same line in `config/environments/development.rb` and it only alert's once. But is this the right way to go?

Comment: Perhaps set: config.assets.debug = false in development.rb? Or just don't precompile in development mode. I know I don't ;-)

Comment: @miked if you add this as an answer, I'll gladly select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config/environments/development.rb try setting:

```
 config.assets.debug = false
```

or just don't precompile your assets in development.  The js is likely executing twice in your development environment because you've precompiled the assets; consequently it's now executing both the script in the original file AND the one you've precompiled.